# Multi-line regex replacement in apache

Tags: apache-2.2, regex

I need to do multi-line replacement in apache2, an mod-substitute only does single line matching AFAIK.

I need to be able to do something like this:

replace

```
<script>
foo = x;
bar = y;
alert(x + y);
</script>
```

with

```
<script>
alert("I'm someone else!");
</script>
```

Is there a way to do this with apache?

Comment: have you tried the usual \n etc. escapesequences? Just a thought.

Comment: That doesn't work in mod_substitute